# How to get single object when using repository pattern?

Tags: c#, database, repository-pattern

I'm using a homebrewed repository pattern (!) together with PetaPoco in my latest project. And when coding some data retrieval routines my brain suddenly made a jump.

Currently i have `Repo.GetMyObjects` that returns an `IList<MyObject>` from the db, and a `Repo.GetMyObject` that returns a `MyObject`.

Is this the correct way to go ahead? Or should I have my `Repo.GetMyObjects` return an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` and then use `Repo.GetMyObjects().SingleOrDefault( q => q.ID == MyWantedObjectID)` in my controller to get a single object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your `Repo.GetMyObject` bet there and make it do what you have described. So that in future if required you can change the implementation and all the callers won't need any change.

Answer (score 1):

To go even further than Ankur's answer: the way you are doing is actually more correct, because having to add `SingleOrDefault()` calls would seem to be something the repository should be doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be stupid to retrieve a whole collection of `MyObject` instances, if you only need one.  Consider the performance-cost that this gives you, if you have thousands of instances in your database.

So, you'll need a `GetMyObject` method in your repository, which retrieves the only object you're interested in.